# Leet Code runtime error: Code wont compile on leet code but compiles in other compilers like netbeans and online compilers

Tags: c

When I try compiling this code on LeetCode it will drop this error:

Runtime Error
Line 10: Char 19: runtime error: member access within misaligned address 0xbebebebebebebebe for type 'struct ListNode', which requires 8 byte alignment [solution.c]
0xbebebebebebebebe: note: pointer points here

I have compiled this code on netbeans and here: https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c_compiler.
It works just fine. I know that the C compiler on LeetCode is a bit finicky. But With some of your help I might try to understand why this is happening.

This is an easy linked list mergeSort off leetcode. Problem number 21. im not sure what else to say besides the fact that I need help fixing the error which is occuring in my Push function at line: 19.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

struct ListNode {
    int val;
    struct ListNode *next;
};

void push(int data, struct ListNode* head){
    struct ListNode* newNode = (struct ListNode*)malloc(sizeof(struct ListNode));
    newNode->val = data;
    
    if(head->val == 0){
        head->val = newNode->val;
    }else{
        struct ListNode* curr = head;
        while(curr->next != NULL){
            curr = curr->next;
        }
        curr->next = newNode;
    }
}
 
struct ListNode* mergeTwoLists(struct ListNode* list1, struct ListNode* list2){
    struct ListNode* mergedList = (struct ListNode*)malloc(sizeof(struct ListNode));
    
    struct ListNode* i = list1;
    struct ListNode* j = list2;
    
    while(i != NULL && j != NULL){
        if(i->val < j->val){
            push(i->val, mergedList);
            i = i->next;
        }else{
            push(j->val, mergedList);
            j = j->next;
        }
    }
    
    while(i != NULL){
        push(i->val, mergedList);
        i = i->next;
    }
    
    while(j != NULL){
        push(j->val, mergedList);
        j = j->next;
    }

    return mergedList;
}

void displayList(struct ListNode *curr){
    while(curr != NULL){
        printf("%d", curr->val);
        curr = curr->next;
    }
}

int main()
{
    struct ListNode* List1 = (struct ListNode*)malloc(sizeof(struct ListNode));
    struct ListNode* List2 = (struct ListNode*)malloc(sizeof(struct ListNode));
    
    struct ListNode* newNode0 = (struct ListNode*)malloc(sizeof(struct ListNode));
    newNode0->val = 1;
    List1 = newNode0;
    
    struct ListNode* newNode1 = (struct ListNode*)malloc(sizeof(struct ListNode));
    newNode1->val = 2;
    List1->next = newNode1;
    
    struct ListNode* newNode2 = (struct ListNode*)malloc(sizeof(struct ListNode));
    newNode2->val = 4;
    List1->next->next = newNode2;
    
    struct ListNode* newNode00 = (struct ListNode*)malloc(sizeof(struct ListNode));
    newNode00->val = 1;
    List2 = newNode00;
    
    struct ListNode* newNode10 = (struct ListNode*)malloc(sizeof(struct ListNode));
    newNode10->val = 3;
    List2->next = newNode10;
    
    struct ListNode* newNode20 = (struct ListNode*)malloc(sizeof(struct ListNode));
    newNode20->val = 4;
    List2->next->next = newNode20;
    
    struct ListNode *mergeL = mergeTwoLists(List1, List2);
    
    displayList(mergeL);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: When do you set the `next` pointers for the end nodes to `NULL`? Looks like never to me. https://godbolt.org/z/Gxsdoe38W

Comment: I am not sure where or how to implement this. I assume you mean when I iterate all the way to the end in push I should set current->next to NULL? I am confused because newNode->next is already pointing to NULL as far as I understand.

Comment: If you were using `calloc` then the allocated memory would be initialized to zero and it would make the `next` pointers `NULL`, but you are not. `malloc` leaves the memory uninitialized and those pointers point to indeterminate places. My advice is to make a function that accepts and int and returns an allocated `ListNode` with `val` set to the parameter passed in and `next` set to `NULL` then replace all of the places you currently use `malloc` with calls to that function.

Comment: How can you say the code doesn't compile? You can't get a runtime error if the code hasn't compiled.

Comment: You should have put https://onlinegdb.com/UVWiq6Q-O instead of https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c_compiler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to assign `NULL` to `next` in the new `struct ListNode`s you create in `push`. Also, you need a `struct ListNode **` to be able to change `head`. It could look like this:

```cpp
void push(int data, struct ListNode **head) {
    // find the pointer pointing at NULL
    while (*head) head = &(*head)->next;
    // allocate memory for the new node:
    *head = malloc(sizeof **head);
    // assign values to both val and next:
    **head = (struct ListNode){data, NULL};
}
```

You then need to adjust the calls to `push` accordingly.

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/PqMnaoqxa)

---

If `push` should be able to create a sorted list, you could adjust it like this:

```c
void push(int data, struct ListNode **head) {
    // find the insertion point:
    for (;*head; head = &(*head)->next) {
        if ((*head)->val > data) break;
    }
    struct ListNode* next = *head;
    // allocate memory for the new node:
    *head = malloc(sizeof **head);
    // assign values to both val and next:
    **head = (struct ListNode){data, next};
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/esasY5KfP)